# local1 cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android

I don not know what I am doing I get this error on Main.1 local1 = new Main.1(this);
Multiple markers at this line

```
- local1 cannot be resolved or is not a field

- Syntax error on token ".1", . expected

- Syntax error on token ".1", delete this token

- The constructor Main(Main) is undefined
```

and then on localGridView.setOnItemClickListener(local1); I get this error
local1 cannot be resolved to a variable

any suggestions?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class Main extends Activity
{
  public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    getWindow().setFlags(1024, 1024);
    setContentView(2130903042);
    setRequestedOrientation(1);
    GridView localGridView = (GridView)findViewById(2131034124);
    ImageAdapter localImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    localGridView.setAdapter(localImageAdapter);
    Main.1 local1 = new Main.1(this);
    localGridView.setOnItemClickListener(local1);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `Main.1` supposed to mean?!

Comment: Its trying to break the code is what its doing!

Comment: It's doing a damn good job too! @Lana - `Main.1` is not valid Java. I have no idea what you're trying to do there.

Comment: I am guessing that you are working with decompiled source. That would explain the long decimal integers instead of `R.` constants for things like `setContentView()`. If you want assistance, you really should explain *why* you are working with decompiled source.

Comment: i think its a pure decomipled source code what u are running.