# Decoding Decompiled Source Code For Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an icon expansion pack for one of my favorite Android apps and the only source I have is some decompiled source. I am not sure what should be in place of "main.1 local1 = new Main.1(this)"

```
Gallery localGallery1 = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.icon_gallery);
IconImageAdapter localIconImageAdapter = new IconImageAdapter(this);
localGallery1.setAdapter(localIconImageAdapter);
Main.1 local1 = new Main.1(this);
localGallery1.setOnItemClickListener(local1);
```

Also, I am not quite sure what the Main.access$0 or this$0 are calling for. Eclipse throws up an error on them.

```
int i = Main.access$0(this.this$0)[paramInt].intValue();
```

And while I am writing my own code, I am using this source as a reference point for mine. I just need help sorting out garbage to understand it a little better. I need to know what Main.1 local1 = new Main.1(this) is talking about. As well as Main.access$0(this.this$0)
Because main.1 isn't correct for Java.

Comment: Sorry. I need to know what Main.1 local1 = new Main.1(this) is talking about. As well as Main.access$0(this.this$0). I read on here that stuff like that shows up only in decompiled source.

Comment: Here's a question like mine about some decompiled source. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5036729

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These mysterious symbols usually correspond to the anonymous inner classes. The Java VM doesn't know about them, only about top-level classes, so the Java compiler provides several workarounds to make inner classes to work.

As far as I can see `Main.1` is some anonymous local implementation of `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`:

```
OnItemClickListener local1 = new OnItemClickListener() {
    // ...
}
```

Local class has implicit reference to the instance of its enclosing class, that is why you see call to `new Main.1(this)`. 'this$0' corresponds to this reference in the decompiled code.

JVM prevents classes from accessing privates methods of other classes so the compiler generates several synthetic package-private methods like `access$0` in order to access private methods of enclosing instance. ["Designing for performance"](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#PackageInner) explains this in more details and recommends to use package-private methods if you need to access them from an inner class.

`intValue` may be called explicitly or be a result of auto unboxing as well.

There are many others features of the Java language that are implemented with synthetic methods like generics and covariant return types.