# what's the meaning of "this.this$0"?

Tags: java, android

what's the meaning of "this.this$0" in this code?
what does it stands for?
I know why we use "this" but I have no idea about "this.this$0"

```
 class MainActivity$1 implements TextWatcher
{
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable paramEditable)
  {
  }

  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence paramCharSequence, int paramInt1, int paramInt2, int paramInt3)
  {
  }

  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence paramCharSequence, int paramInt1, int paramInt2, int paramInt3)
  {
    this.this$0.ChangeToNumber(paramCharSequence.toString());
  }
}
-----------------------or ----------------------
class MainActivity$2 implements View.OnClickListener
{
  public void onClick(View paramView)
  {
    this.this$0.startActivity(new Intent(this.this$0, about.class));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**this.this$0** it's same to **Main.access$0**
These mysterious symbols usually correspond to the anonymous inner classes. The Java VM doesn't know about them, only about top-level classes, so the Java compiler provides several workarounds to make inner classes to work.

Local class has implicit reference to the instance of its enclosing class,'this$0' corresponds to this reference in the decompiled code.
JVM prevents classes from accessing privates methods of other classes so the compiler generates several synthetic package-private methods like access$0 in order to access private methods of enclosing instance.

There are many others features of the Java language that are implemented with synthetic methods like generics and covariant return types.

I suggest you to check those links:
[Decoding Decompiled Source Code For Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542906/decoding-decompiled-source-code-for-android)

and : [Performance Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#PackageInner)

Comment: Just FWIW, if you are using Java >= 8, lambdas will have similar signatures.

Answer (score 5):

this$0 normally is for the parent object of a `non-static` inner class. E.g.,

```
public class Outer {
    class Inner1 {
        int f1 = 1;
    }

    static class Inner2 {
        int f1 = 2;
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer o = new Outer();
        Outer.Inner1 i1 = o.new Inner1(); //weird but valid
        Outer.Inner2 i2 = new Outer.Inner2(); //normal
        //wrong: Outer.Inner1 i3 = new Outer.Inner1();
    }
}
```

Normally we define inner class as `static`. `i2` has only 1 field, but `i1` has an extra `this$0` which points to `o`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing preventing you (beside decent naming conventions) from having an instance member called `this$0` and then referring to it with the `this` keyword.

For example :

```
public class SomeClass
{
    int this$0;
    public SomeClass (int val) 
    {
        this.this$0 = val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Java 1.1 Language Specification specifies that the name of a type which is a class member, when transformed into Java 1.0 code for the purpose of generating Java virtual machine bytecodes, consists of the fully qualified name of the inner class, except that each `.' character following a class name is replaced by a`$'. In addition, each inner class constructor receives the enclosing instance in a prepended argument. Here is how the transformed source code of the FixedStack example might look:

```
public class FixedStack {
        ... (the methods omitted here are unchanged)
        public java.util.Enumeration elements() {
            return new FixedStack$Enumerator(this);
        }
    }

    class FixedStack$Enumerator implements java.util.Enumeration {
        private FixedStack this$0; // saved copy of FixedStack.this
        FixedStack$Enumerator(FixedStack this$0) {
            this.this$0 = this$0;
            this.count = this$0.top;
        }

        int count;
        public boolean hasMoreElements() {
            return count > 0;
        }
        public Object nextElement() {
            if (count == 0)
                throw new NoSuchElementException("FixedStack");
            return this$0.array[--count];
        }
    }
```

Anyone who has already programmed with Java or C++ adapter classes has written code similar to this, except that the link variables must be manually defined and explicitly initialized in top-level adapter classes, whereas the Java 1.1 compiler creates them automatically for inner classes.

When the Enumerator needs to refer to the top or array fields of the enclosing instance, it indirects through a private link called this$0. The spelling of this name is a mandatory part of the transformation of inner classes to the Java 1.0 language, so that debuggers and similar tools can recognize such links easily. (Most programmers are happily unaware of such names.)

(Note: There is a limitation in some implementations of Java 1.1, under which the initialization of this$0 is delayed until after any superclass constructor is run. This means that up-level references made by a subclass method may fail if the method happens to be executed by the superclass constructor.)