# read parent class members from inner class get old values

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have simple an inner class declared as such `private class ColumnResolver`
that is instantiated in the parent class like that `private final ColumnResolver columnResolver = new ColumnResolver();`

When I when access members from the outer class from the inner class (OuterClass.this.InnerClass), members have wrong values.

[image: intellij screenshot]

I expected to have 3 and 8 and not 0 and 0 as seen in the picture.

There is no multi-threading involved, I don't understand what's going on...

Also, it seems like `this` and `this$0` don't reference the same object? (not the same id).

It's like the VM assigns a cloned object to `this$0` and not the actual parent class instance.

What could possibly cause this?

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.14" 2022-01-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment SapMachine (build 11.0.14+9-LTS-sapmachine)         
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM SapMachine (build 11.0.14+9-LTS-sapmachine, mixed mode)
```

Comment: you need to show a [mcve]

Comment: You may look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50093487/5116356 for the meaning of ´this$0´, that is not exactly the same as ´this´.

Comment: @luca.vercelli In the example of Leon this$0 points to this and both have points to Outer@525. In my case, you see 2 different instances

Comment: @MiniScalope No, not exactly. In his example, if you use "this" inside the inner class Inner1, its value will be object@526 whereas this$0 will be object@525

Comment: @luca.vercelli this$0 points to Outer@525. and this in the outer class context points also to Outer@525. So everything is alright. In my case, I have 2 different Outer class instances 4590 and 4581. Wich is completely weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out Mockito was messing up things.

That is why I had different instances of the inner and outer class.

When I wrap the outer class with spy(), it messes things up, and the inner class reads/writes from some cloned object...